# eXist-db passing parameters to templates through controller.xql (URL mapping)

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I am working with eXist-db 4.2.1 and Xquery 3.1 using the eXist's default installation of `controller.xql` and `view.xq`.

I have a `document.html` to which I pass any incoming url structured with `/doc/some-requested-doc-id` at the end to produce a dynamically-created page based on `some-requested-doc-id`.

So, the incoming url can be either `http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/deheresi/doc/MS609-0001` or 
    `http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/deheresi/doc/MS609-0001.xml`

and they are treated the same...

In the file `controller.xql` I have a condition for matching this request, which identifies `/doc/` and cleans up the expected `some-requested-doc-id` using a [function](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_substring-before-match.html) which is passed to parameter `name="currentdoc"`:

```
 [...]
 else if (starts-with($exist:path, "/doc/")) then
    (: strip out any extensions and rename global variable as .xml:)
        <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
        <forward url="{$exist:controller}/document.html">
            <add-parameter name="currentdoc" 
             value="{concat(functx:substring-before-match($exist:resource,'[.]'),'.xml')}"/>
        </forward>
            <view>
                <forward url="{$exist:controller}/modules/view.xql"/>
            </view>
        </dispatch>
 [...]
```

The requested .html file is as follows, which itself calls other HTML templates and/or dynamically created content in XQuery:

```
 <div data-template="templates:surround" data-template-with="templates/site_wrapper.html" data-template-at="content">

<div data-template="document:title-bar"/>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
        <div data-template="document:doc-sidebar-sub1"/>
        <div data-template="document:doc-sidebar-sub2"/>
        <div data-template="document:doc-sidebar-sub3"/>
        <div data-template="document:doc-sidebar-sub4"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 document-view">
        <div data-template="document:doc-xsl-docview"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The 5  `data-template="document:...` calls [depend on the same parameter provided](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/templating#D3.31) by `<add-parameter>`, for example `<div data-template="document:title-bar"/>` calls:

```
declare function document:title-bar( 
     $node as node(), 
     $model as map(*), 
     $currentdoc as xs:string)
{   

let $persid := person:person-name(data(doc(concat($globalvar:URIdata,$currentdoc))/tei:TEI/tei:text//tei:persName[@role="dep"]/@nymRef)) 
let $doctypeen := data(doc(concat($globalvar:URIdata,$currentdoc))/tei:TEI/tei:text//tei:div[@type="doc_type"]/@subtype)

let $x :=
<div class="col-md-12 document-title">
    <h2><span class="en">{$doctypeen}: </span><span class="fr">{document:doc-type-french($doctypeen)} : </span>{$persid}</h2>
</div>

return $x
};
```

Even if I hard-code the parameter in the module `controller.xql`:

```
 <add-parameter name="currentdoc" value="MS609-00001.xml"/>
```

I still get the same error, which doesn't happen if I hard code the parameter in the template call:

```
 The actual cardinality for parameter 3 does not match the 
 cardinality declared in the function's signature: 
 document:title-bar($node as node(), $model as map, 
      $currentdoc as xs:string) item()*. 
 Expected cardinality: exactly one, got 0.
```

The 'expected cardinality' suggests that the parameter is not coming into the function?

EDIT:

If I change the order of parameters in the function above to

```
 declare function document:title-bar( 
     $currentdoc as xs:string, 
     $node as node(), 
     $model as map(*))
```

I get a different error:

```
  Supplied argument 2 of function: 
  document:title-bar($currentdoc as xs:string, 
  $node as node(), $model as map) item()* does not 
  match required type. Required type node(), got map. `
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you confirm that the parameter name set in the controller is identical to the variable name in your `document:title-bar()` function's signature? They are identical in the sample code here (they're both `currentdoc`), but I just wanted to check that this is also the case on your system where you're getting the error. (Also, something insignificant for the purposes of this question: in your hard-coded `<add-parameter>` example, you have a trailing single quote (`'`) after `.xml`.)

Comment: Yes, in fact all the above is copy-paste from my code. I removed the single quote and retested with same result, thank you (now updated above).

Comment: This is the .xar for the project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xtxjjmk9tkkqnj/deheresi-2018-10-30%201833.xar?dl=0 the relevant file names are exactly as described above.

Comment: Excellent. It was very helpful to have the .xar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<add-parameter>` directive needs to be moved to the 2nd `<forward>` directive—so that `modules/view.xql` has access to the parameter. The corrected version of this fragment of your controller is:

```
else if (starts-with($exist:path, "/doc/")) then
    (: strip out any extensions and rename global variable as .xml:)
    <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
        <forward url="{$exist:controller}/document.html"/>
        <view>
            <forward url="{$exist:controller}/modules/view.xql">
                <add-parameter name="currentdoc" value="{concat(functx:substring-before-match($exist:resource,'[.]'),'.xml')}"/>
            </forward>
        </view>
    </dispatch>
```

The templating documentation also shows this - see the 2nd code sample under the "Set up" section here: https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/templating#D3.35.

(There was a mistake in the answer you referenced - which I have now corrected. Apologies, and thanks for your thorough testing and well-articulated questions!)

Comment: Thanks for this, it works! One question: is there an eXist system 'constant' to refer to the path of the application? For example, if the installation was at `http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/` and the  app `deheresi` was the current environment, the 'constant' would return 'http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/deheresi' ? I've seen some solutions that pull apart `system:get-module-load-path()`....

Comment: See if your app's `modules/config.xqm` declares a global variable, `$config:app-root`. That determines the app's installation path dynamically.